# How to get a distance matrix using "SVRspell"?

Tags: sequence-analysis, traminer

I am trying to compute a distance matrix using the method "SVRspell" (seqdistOO function).

I want to use an exponential weight of spell length equal to 2 and I want to discard matching sub-sequences of length one. No states' similarity matrix.

**Note:** sequences in the 'seqs' object below have a length of 25 (ages 15 to 39) and the alphabet has 20 states (marital status plus children ever born).

So, I run this

`>svr<-seqdistOO(seqs, method="SVRspell", tpow=2, kweights=sqrt(c(0,2:25)))
[>] 6315 sequences with 20 distinct events/states
[>] 5023 distinct sequences
[>] min/max sequence length: 1/11
[>] computing distances using NMSMST metric
[>] total time: 30.41 secs`

I do not understand why it seems to be using a *NMSMST* metric instead of the *SVRspell* with the specified parameters. In my understanding SVRspell is not equivalent to NMSMST

Am I coding something wrong? or is it because *SVRspell* pertains to the 'family' of *NMS* metrics?

Thanks,

Andres

Comment: You might be better on a site specific to your software unless you want to separate out the statistical part from the programming part.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct and the "`... using NMSMST`" message is just a display bug.

Actually, the NMS, NMSMST, and SVRspell methods proposed by the package `seqdist2`, all use a same algorithm. The difference is controlled by a few internal parameters.

Comment: Thank you, it is good to know I was doing the right thing.

Comment: Package `seqdist2` is now obsolete. Its content (with many improvements) has been made directly available in `TraMineR` since v 2.0-5. See the documentation page of the `seqdist` and `seqcost` functions.